# Json Encoding Format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to make an iPhone app which remotely connects to a db and runs queries. I have a php script which runs the query and encodes the result array into json. I have been following this tutorial (http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/) and currently have the same code for the php file. However, when I echo the json array I get output that differs in formatting.

The tutorial that I am following has output of the following format;

```
[
   - {
        Name: "Apple",
        Address: "1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CAL"
      }, 
...
```

However, I see something like this:

```
[{"Name":"Apple", "Address":"1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CAL"}], ....
```

I am confused, are those the same or not (do I have associative keys)? Can somebody explain what may cause the difference in output (same code) and how to alter the format to the desired one? Later when I am am printing out the json array in Xcode logs I will see inconsistencies such as:

```
"Name" = Apple;
Address = "Infinite Loop Cupertino, CAL";
...
```

(I even get the format "x" = "x";)

Here is a the code in the php file:

```
$con->set_charset("utf8");
$resultArray = array();

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $resultArray[] = $row;
    }
}

echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Comment: What you are getting is valid JSON. The first example you show is **not** valid JSON. I'm assuming it's a debugger view or an example, but it's certainly not JSON. Both seem to show the same data structure though, so all seems to be fine.

Comment: So my problem is likely in how i download the Json file in Xcode... Thank you for clearing this out for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed getting valid JSON, `json_encode` prints by default the minimal version, by not including spaces and newlines etc.

What you are probably seeing is `json_encode` with the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag specified:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

(I've not checked this so I can't be sure, my version of PHP is old)

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php for more information

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will focus on how I download my Json on Xcode to fix my issue.